# compiles in atom but not terminal

Tags: c++, g++, atom-editor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream fout = ofstream("fout.txt");
}
```

this code compiles fine in atom using the script package by rgbkrk (which uses g++) but when I try to compile it on the terminal using g++ I get the following output.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o hw
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:39:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/streambuf:493:64: error: 
      base class 'std::__1::ios_base' has private copy constructor
_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(class _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE_TYPE_VIS basic_ios<char>)
                                                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:147:32: note: 
      in implicit copy constructor for 'std::__1::basic_ios<char>' first
      required here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_ofstream;
                               ^
test.cpp:6:19: note: in implicit copy constructor for
      'std::__1::basic_ofstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' first
      required here
  ofstream fout = ofstream("fout.txt");
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:313:5: note: 
      declared private here
    ios_base(const ios_base&); // = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: @Shawn You want _the answer section_

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, that's not actually GCC. I know it looks like it is, because you executed `g++`, but the output indicates that you're on macOS, and on macOS `g++` is actually Clang in disguise. Yes, it's stupid.

Secondly, before C++17 you could not use *copy-initialisation* like that for non-copyable things like streams. Even though redundant copies were often elided, they always had to be possible.

So, instead of:

```
ofstream fout = ofstream("file.txt");
```

you should have written just a nice simple declaration:

```
ofstream fout("file.txt");
```

or:

```
ofstream fout{"file.txt"};
```

(ew)

In C++17, the rules changed and the elision is now *mandatory*, as well as no longer requiring the hypothetical copy to be possible. So, in C++17 mode, your code should work.

Your manual `g++` invocation does not contain any switch to turn on C++17 mode, which is apparently not the default for your version of Clang.

Always specify your desired language standard version explicitly. My go-to command is:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17 test.cpp -o hw
```

Comment: I like the subtle recommendation for using extra warning flags.